# Haskell: How to prove(test) whether a self-defined Monad instance follow Monad laws?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

Not using formal deduction, how can I test whether a self-defined `Monad` instance follows the Monad laws?

Comment: Well proving something somehow will mean (formal) deduction (or by contradiction) of another mathematical technique. Without it, you can generate a lot of *empirical* evidence, but that is not a "proof". There are however some automated proof systems ("code contracts") that might (or might not) do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, here's a set of QuickCheck properties I recently wrote that tests the Monad laws for a Maybe implementation derived from its F-Algebra:

```
testProperty "Monad left identity law" $ do
  a :: String <- arbitrary
  k :: String -> MaybeFix Integer <- (fromMaybe .) <$> arbitrary

  let left = return a >>= k
  let right = k a

  return $ left == right
,
testProperty "Monad right identity law" $ do
  m :: MaybeFix Integer <- fromMaybe <$> arbitrary

  let left = m >>= return
  let right = m

  return $ left == right
,
testProperty "Monad associativity law" $ do
  m :: MaybeFix String <- fromMaybe <$> arbitrary
  k :: String -> MaybeFix Integer <- (fromMaybe .) <$> arbitrary
  h :: Integer -> MaybeFix Ordering <- (fromMaybe .) <$> arbitrary

  let left = m >>= (\x -> k x >>= h)
  let right = (m >>= k) >>= h

  return $ left == right
```

Comment: Sure, but that's not a proof, that's just empirical evidence

Comment: @Cubic The OP uses both terms (prove and test), but appears to be interested in testing, not proving.

Comment: Sorry for asking for so details, but how can I make this work?

Comment: @Yellowsgg The code posted here shows three inlined properties, written in [a style I've described in an article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/05/07/inlined-hunit-test-lists). For a general overview of my approach to testing in Haskell, you could refer to my article [Typing and testing problem 23](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/07/09/typing-and-testing-problem-23).

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you know what Monad laws are, but I'll [link them](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws) for the sake of completeness.

Since you explicitly mentioned testing as opposed to formal proving, you can use one of the automated testing frameworks for Haskell, e.g. [QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) or [Hspec](https://hspec.github.io/).

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit over the top, but you can try [hs-to-coq](https://github.com/antalsz/hs-to-coq), which might be able to convert your hs code to Coq code, which you can then prove things about using [Coq (a Proof Assistant)](https://coq.inria.fr/).

For an example of proving monad laws using Coq (though this was not using hs-to-coq), see:
https://github.com/jwiegley/coq-pipes#laws-proven